# How can I redirect a custom subdomain to a github-pages project when the domain itself is set to S3?

Tags: dns, subdomain, github-pages

I have read several questions about custom domains pointing to a github-pages website. However, I could not find the answer for my case.

- I have an apex domain (e.g. `http://example.com`) pointing to an S3
  bucket.
- I have a `www` redirection to this apex domain.
- I have an existing organization project website on github pages that
  I can access using an url like this:
  `http://ORGANIZATION.github.io/blog`

I want to access that github-page hosted website using a subdomain, like `blog.example.com` while keeping my apex set to my S3 bucket.

Most of the answers I found were to redirect the domain apex to `http://ORGANIZATION.github.io/` and access to the blog using "www.example.com/blog". It is not what I want.

Since `ORGANIZATION.github.io/blog.` is not a valid CNAME record, I can no use it as value for my sub domain CNAME record.

Is there a way to use a github pages organization project website with a custom subdomain?

Comment: If you have a www server already you could do a re-direct or something in a `.htaccess` file thus removing the need to do anything with the git side of things

Comment: I managed to do it on my own. I will post a detailed answer once I'm allowed to. Thank you for the comment I was feeling lonely ^^.

Comment: no worries glad you sorted it :)

Comment: please post an answer when you can @Billybobbonnet ! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it can be complicated to figure this out when not familiar with domain names management, I will try to explain what can be and what cannot be done.

Every domain name has an apex, i.e. the domain name without subdomain.

Exemple: `http://example.com`

Note that `www` is a sub domain (`http://www.example.com`) that you can redirect to your apex.

With Github-Pages, with an organization account, you can only link the apex or a subdomain to a repo with a name formated as follow: `orgname.github.io`. You also need to set the domain in the repo settings.

If you have a repo with a different name (i.e. blog), it can be only available with an URL like this: `http://example.com/blog`

This is not what I want. So what I did was to create one organization per subdomain. I hope that it is not considered as an abuse to github-pages terms.

For example, I create a `myorg_blog` organization with a repo called `myorg_blog.github.io` that point to my subdomain `blog.example.com`. Same thing for the portfolio: another organization with a single repo.

Then I keep the apex pointing to S3, no changes to make on this part.